# Why PHP not working with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, scripting

A very popular answer in StackOvwerflow suggested that in order to get any php variable within a javascript, simply use php withi angular brackets.

```
var x= <?php echo "val"; ? >
```

. However I see that the script given below entirely fails to run If I use this method.
Once I comment out that line script works fine.

```
<script>
var test=<?php echo "hi"; ?>;
alert(test);
document.title=test;
</script>
```

Even this simple script is not working.

1. The page is saved as .php
2. The page resides in WAMP server and is accessed as localhost/test.php

.
.

*EDIT: Full code*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<script>
    var test=<?php echo "hi"; ?>;
    alert(test);
    document.title=test;
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="test-canvas" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the rendered output and/or the console...

Comment: Sorry If I sound stupid..but I am running from web browser not console. An alert must pop up.. If I remove the php, alerts come up just fine.

Comment: You're echoing a string, and even javascript requires quotes -> `var x= '<?php echo "val" >';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your omitted the ' ' in the script

```
<script>var test = '<?php echo $variable; ?>';</script>
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your php is:

```
var test=hi;
```

And that will make a problem because javascript needs quotes too when dealing with strings.

You can do this to solve the issue:

```
var test=<?php echo "'hi'"; ?>;
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for your notice, I modified it with the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
var test = '<?php echo "anything"; ?>';
alert(test);
```